# C# Explicitly override virtual interface method of base type

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I have an abstract class `DataBase` which is used as base class for different types of data, such as simple value types (`byte`, `int`, `string` etc.) and more complex data structures like `DataList` and `DataDictionary`. DataList implements `IList<DataBase>` and DataDictionary implements `IDictionary<string, DataBase>`.

For simplicity's sake, I went ahead and put a couple of things I'll often use in the DataBase class, so casting won't be necessary:

```
public virtual DataBase this[string name] {
    get { throw new NotSuppportedException(); }
    set { throw new NotSuppportedException(); }
}
public virtual DataBase this[int index] { ...

// Example usage:
var someData = rootData["SomeList"][10];
```

These methods are then overridden in base classes. Or not, in which case it throws the exception when used. To make things a little simpler I also wanted to implement `IEnumerable<DataBase>` in a similar way:

```
public virtual IEnumerator<DataBase> GetEnumerator() {
    throw new NotSuppportedException();
}
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

But since DataDictionary is an IDictionary, and therefore `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DataBase>>`, I've run into the issue of not being able to override DataBase's `GetEnumerator()`. I've tried a number of different ways:

```
(public|protected) (override) IEnumerator<DataBase> DataBase.GetEnumerator()
(public|protected) (override) IEnumerator<DataBase> IEnumerable<DataBase>.GetEnumerator()
```

> The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item (CS0106)

Now, I wasn't sure what to look for regarding this issue - what is this called even? - or which limitation (if any) is preventing me from doing what I'm trying to do and why it may be there.

---

Related question and answer ["C# overriding an interface contract method of a base class"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932068/1726609) does not solve the issue. If you were to change `x`'s type to `TestBase`, the code outputs "Base".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# spec explicitly disallows the use of `override` on an explicitly implemented interface member in section [13.4.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664591%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> It is a compile-time error for an explicit interface member implementation to include access modifiers, and it is a compile-time error to include the modifiers `abstract`, `virtual`, `override`, or `static`.

So if you want to override `DataBase::GetEnumerator()` in `DataDictionary`, you need a non-explicit implementation. But in order to write an override using a non-explicit implementation, you must have explicitly implemented `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DataBase>>::GetEnumerator()`, because if you use a non-explicit implementation for *that* method, it will hide `DataBase::GetEnumerator()`, since the two methods differ only by their return types.

Bottom line: I can't see why you'd want to design something like this. (You seem to have arrived at the same conclusion in your answer when you described it as "*doing-something-way-too-silly-and-complicated!*")

Comment: I guess I reached the same conclusion through my experimentation. Thanks for the finding where this is mentioned in the spec. Definitely something I should check myself in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I've previously run into these sort of issues, which is often a case of *doing-something-way-too-silly-and-complicated*. One obvious solution I can think of is moving the implementation into the `DataBase` class directly:

```
public IEnumerator<DataBase> GetEnumerator() {
    if (this is DataList)
        return ((DataList)this).GetEnumerator();
    else if (this is DataDictionary)
        return ((DataDictionary)this).Values.GetEnumerator();
    else throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

But obviously, it's definitely not the cleanest solution.